# I get myself as friend when executing method un repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I am checking for friends that has accepted my friend request and thus are my real friends. But when displaying my friends I get myself as friend and not the person I have for friend sometimes. This appears when for example my id is second in the table.

I have tried checking if the userid is in either of the columns. Also tried with having two way friendship like A friend with B but B friend with A too. I couldnt get the repository work for the second method so I sticked to this one.

My repository:

```
public function personalFriends($userId){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $result = $em->createQuery('SELECT friends FROM AppBundle\Entity\Friends friends 
    INNER JOIN AppBundle\Entity\User myuser WHERE (friends.friendsWithMe = :userId OR friends.afriendof = :userId) AND friends.friends = 1');
    $result->setParameter('userId', $userId);
    return $result->getResult();
}
```

My controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();
    $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(UserPosts::class)->findUserPosts($userId,1);
    $friends = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Friends::class)->personalFriends($userId);



    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig',
        ['formed' => null,
            'posts' => $posts,
            'posted'=>null,
            'search' => null,
            'friends' => $friends
        ]);
}
```

My view :

```
    <div class="card card-body">
            {{ app.user.username|capitalize }}'s friends:
            {% if friends %}
                <div>
                {% for friend in friends %}
                    {{ friend.afriendof.username }}
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div>
                    You have no friends.
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Friends Entity:

```
class Friends
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="myfriends", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */

private $friendsWithMe;


/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="friendof", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */

private $afriendof;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="request_sent", type="smallint")
 */
private $requestSent;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="friends", type="smallint")
 */

private $friends;
```

I want to get only the friends and not myself. I get that I have to change the `friend.afriendof.username` with `friend.friendswithme.username`, but how to know when to change between those two.

Comment: What is the difference between `afriendof` and `friendswithme` ?

Comment: @Cid there is none in the moment, because my id can stay in afriendof or friendswithme for example afriendof(45)-friendswithme(12). But nothing can obligate me to be in that order. Here is the problem too. Because afriendof(45)-friendswithme(12), and afriendof(11)-friendswithme(45) and I can not make it show names only of users with id 12 and 11, because my id is 45. I get once 12 and once 45 for example right now.